# How to use existing hook in twentytwelve to all theme of wordpress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

I Recently tried to read the tutorial for `wp_footer` and also `twentytwelve_credits` for creating a sample wordpress plugins.
`wp_footer` hook to display the footer beneath the page area.
 `twentytwelve_credits` hook display the footer in the page footer on a white background.
**For Example:**
I tried this code to show the footer with custom message.

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
?>
```

I tried this code after switching a theme to twenty twelve.

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action('twentytwelve_credits', 'your_function');
?>
```

I find the difference when using different hooks. `wp_footer` hook is working for all themes but it is in bottom of the site. `twentytwelve_credits` is working for the twentytwelve theme only. I beleive twentytwelve_credits is the efficient way rather than wp_footer. but its hard to change the hook for every theme. I am not sure is the way to show of the footer with every theme with twentytwelve_credits. Any Possibilities like `do_action('twentytwelve_credits');`.
Any Suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hook can only be implemented via actual function call. It is not possible without adding that call to theme template directly or via other method (calling it inside another, already available, hook for example).

There is [Theme Hook Alliance](http://zamoose.github.io/themehookalliance/) initiative to promote more standardized hooks in themes and increase flexibility, but adoption have been low so far and usually hooks in theme are specific to it or (at best) to a theme framework used.